# Bean and SQL Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am building a simple CRUD operation using Spring Boot, MySQL and Hibernate need help in this operation. Searched a lot at Google and StackOverflow didn't found an appropriate solution.

Issues on: The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the `serverTimezone` configuration property) to use a more specific time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

```
com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
```

The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

```
Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.jdbcStatement(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]

[PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution


Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution


 Error creating bean with name 'digitalEmployeeRepo' defined in com.eg.demo.repository.DigitalEmployeeRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
```

.................................................................
My codes.
.............
Controller
...........................

```
package com.eg.demo.controller;

import com.eg.demo.model.DigitalEmployee;
import com.eg.demo.service.DigitalEmployeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import java.util.List;

public class DigitalController {
    @Autowired
    DigitalEmployeeService digitalEmployeeService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/DigitalEmployee/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<DigitalEmployee>> listAllUsers() {
        List<DigitalEmployee> digitalEmployees = digitalEmployeeService.allEmployee();
        if (digitalEmployees.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);

        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<DigitalEmployee>>(digitalEmployees, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // -------------------Retrieve Single User------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/digitalEmployee/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

        DigitalEmployee digitalEmployee = digitalEmployeeService.findById(id);

        return new ResponseEntity<DigitalEmployee>(digitalEmployee, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // -------------------Create a User-------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/digitalEmployee/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createEmployee(@RequestBody DigitalEmployee digitalEmployee) {
        digitalEmployeeService.save(digitalEmployee);
        return new ResponseEntity<DigitalEmployee>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    // ------------------- Update a User ------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/digitalEmployee/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateEmployee(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody DigitalEmployee digitalEmployee) {
        DigitalEmployee currentEmployee = digitalEmployeeService.findById(id);

        currentEmployee.setName(digitalEmployee.getName());
        digitalEmployeeService.update(currentEmployee);
        return new ResponseEntity<DigitalEmployee>(currentEmployee, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // ------------------- Delete a User-----------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/digitalEmployee/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        DigitalEmployee digitalEmployee = digitalEmployeeService.findById(id);
        digitalEmployeeService.deleteById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<DigitalEmployee>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

    // ------------------- Delete All Users-----------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/DigitalEmployee/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<DigitalEmployee> deleteAll() {

        digitalEmployeeService.deleteAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<DigitalEmployee>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

}
```

model
.................

```
package com.eg.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DigitalEmployee")
public class DigitalEmployee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;

    public DigitalEmployee() {
    }

    public DigitalEmployee(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

...........
repo
.............

```
package com.eg.demo.repository;

import com.eg.demo.model.DigitalEmployee;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface DigitalEmployeeRepo extends CrudRepository<DigitalEmployee, Long> {
}
```

...............................
service
............

```
package com.eg.demo.service;

import com.eg.demo.model.DigitalEmployee;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface DigitalEmployeeService {
    void save(DigitalEmployee digitalEmployee);
    void update(DigitalEmployee digitalEmployee);
    void deleteAll();
    void deleteById(Long id);
    DigitalEmployee findById(Long id);
    List<DigitalEmployee> allEmployee();

}
```

.............
service Impl
..................

```
package com.eg.demo.service;

import com.eg.demo.model.DigitalEmployee;
import com.eg.demo.repository.DigitalEmployeeRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class DigitalEmployeeServiceImpl implements DigitalEmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    DigitalEmployeeRepo digitalEmployeeRepo;

    public void save(DigitalEmployee digitalEmployee) {
        digitalEmployeeRepo.save(digitalEmployee);
    }

    public void update(DigitalEmployee digitalEmployee) {
        save(digitalEmployee);
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
         digitalEmployeeRepo.deleteAll();
    }

    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        digitalEmployeeRepo.deleteById(id);
    }

    public DigitalEmployee findById(Long id) {
        return digitalEmployeeRepo.findById(id).get();
    }

    public List<DigitalEmployee> allEmployee() {
        return (List<DigitalEmployee>) digitalEmployeeRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

............
main method
...........

```
package com.eg.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;


//@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.*")
@EnableSwagger2
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@ComponentScan("com.eg.demo")

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

................
applicaion properties
............................

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/digital
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

.......................
pom
...............................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.eg</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.9.2</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->



        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.9.2</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>io.springfox</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.9.2</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!---->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I think the driver class name should be `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Answer (score 0):

config the timezone with the datasource url property, just like this
url:jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai

Comment: I would rather commend using UTC here, you'll end up with issues that are hard to debug down the line otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/digital?serverTimezone=UTC